# How can I use asynchronous code in synchronous Python code?

Tags: python, concurrency

I'm developing django 2.2 (with mySql database) application with some code to import data from csv sources.
Code is synchronous:

1. load next csv line and do some pre-processing (normalize/sanitize
   input data)
2. create or update django model from input data (and perform database
   read/write)

There are obvious bottlenecks here:

- disk i/o on reading line from csv file (few files with more than 4M
  records)
- network i/o on database communication (tcp/ip socket)

The process could be optimized:
Read input data, then pass it to asynchronous code for database operation - fire and forget. Instead of waiting for DB to finish, load next csv line.

What is your recommendations on optimization strategy in this case?

Comment: CPU or I/O intensive tasks should not be processed in any WSGI application. You should consider using a task queue (like Celery for example) to process heavy tasks.

Comment: Import code currently is implemented as django command. For now, i run it manually (still in development). I plan to use Celery as automation service. Later.

Answer (score 0):

for your question...

try to use django with gevent

1) uses 'csv' lib and 'csv.reader' and loop on the on the returned element from 'csv.reader' call

2) uses Mysqldb or pymsql as the django orm's dialect lib to access your database asynchronously